# IE10 breaks CSS3 3D animations working in Webkit & Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, css, css-animations, internet-explorer-10

I have a simple horizontal CSS3 3D flip effect on two `div`s which runs fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. But IE10 screws it up and does some strange additional animations on all axis as it seems.

[image: IE10 animation]

I've tracked it down to the additional `translateX` animation. If I remove it and only do the `rotateY`, IE10 behaves just like the other browsers. But I don't want to renounce the x-axis animation.

Please have a look at the issue in this jsFiddle (only IE & Webkit for clarity): http://jsfiddle.net/uJnHE/5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your webkit prefixes and add `translateX(0)`, because IE10 beta doesn't know how to transition between an undeclared transform propery and `translateX(-200px)`

```
@keyframes flipHotelInfoLeft {
  0% {
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      transform: rotateY(180deg) translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
      transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(200px);
  }
  100% {
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      transform: rotateY(0) translateX(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected the mistake in the jsFiddle, however the broken IE10 behavior did not change at all.

Comment: Worth giving a try: add `transform: rotateY(0) translateX(0)` to your 0% keyframes. The problem might be that IE10 doesn't know how to interpolate between `undefined` and `translateX(-200px)`.

Comment: Great suggestion, that did it! Got to love IE10 ;-) http://jsfiddle.net/uJnHE/17/ - Mind to add the idea at the top of your original answer, so I can accept it and everyone else will find the useful content right away?

Comment: Done, hopefully this will get fixed before the final release, as it's correct according to spec.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tested this with the release version available since August 15th in MSDN...

Comment: Yep, this still happens in IE10 final. Slow clap.